# python dict KeyError for unicode strings only when large number of keys stored

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have an OrderedDict with 3000+ entries. In the sample program with 3 entries when I store keys in Unicode format I am able to do a lookup without any issues for any key. However in the OrderedDict with 3000+ unique key entries I get an error for the entry "Ha Nội" while doing a lookup. The error I get is KeyError: 'Ha N\xc3\xa1\xc2\xbb\x99i'. 
Giving example code here which works fine. Why this difference?

```
> recs = ( ("Sant Julià de Loria", "X"), ("Ha Nội", "Y") )
> 
> OrdD = OrderedDict(recs)  
  HVal = OrdD["Ha Nội"] 
  print(HVal)
```

I am using Python 3.4.3.

Comment: what file encoding are you using for the source files? Or are recs coming from a file you are reading? (and in which encoding?)

Comment: And are you sure you are using Python 3.4.3 here?

Comment: Also, you appear to have a *Mojibake*, wrongly decoded data. I can't even get `ftfy` to repair it.

Comment: From PHP, MySQL i never had this issue. In case of python I face this issue only when I store 3000+ such records. @martijn Yes I use Python3.4.3

Comment: The reason I don't believe you is that Python 3.4 will **not** use escape sequences like that. Python 2 would. In Python 3 you get the message `KeyError: 'Ha NÃ¡Â»\x99i'` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I use the below code as a temporary fix. recs = (
("Sant Julià de Loria", "X"),
("Ha Nội", "Y"),
("Ha bu", "Z")
)

OrdD = OrderedDict(recs)
gotit = None
idx = 0

for i, value in OrdD.items():
    idx = idx+1
    if i == "Ha Nội":
        gotit = value
        break

print("idx:"+str(idx))
print("gotit:"+gotit) I assume OrdD.items() works in python 3.x only. Just to test against your query.

Comment: @birdypme (1)I use Unicode(UTF-8), LineBreaks Unix(LF) using textwrangler version 4.5.12. I edit my code in mac os x Yosemite with textwrangler deploy it in cent OS with python3.4.3. PS: Sample program I quoted was executed in mac with python3.4.2. (2) Records are stored as part of source code without explicit external file reading

Comment: No, `OrdD.items()` works fine in Python 2 too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I printed the version with the below code     version = ".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])) 
    print(version) and the version is 3.4.3; The code runs in an apache web server with WSGI.

Comment: @Vinodh: Right, this is probably your console codec being too limited again; Python 3 will use the `'backslashreplace'` error handler if writing the original causes issues. What does `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` say is your console encoding? Your key error still shows you have a Mojibake, that it throws a key error is not surprising.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks.
content = io.StringIO()
content.write(sys.stdout.encoding)
prints utf-8 in the browser. This code is part of .wsgi file deployed in apache.
I have to store and process these characters succefully. Not sure whats the mistake in the approach.

Comment: @Vinodh: so how did you get the key error? How was the exception encoded?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the error is written to the apache log file which is printed in the console with tail -10 /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

Comment: Also I dont think its a Mojibake as it is displayed properly when printed in the sample program. It is only the issue with the dictionary key.